# Create list from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a feeling this is really simple. Here's the deal: I have a table with three columns. I want to take all the values in one of the columns and turn that into a list. I want to do this so I can transverse through the list. Each value in the list corresponds to a username. I want to take that username to access info about a user. Using this info, I can check which faculty the user is in and sort accordingly. This is what I've come up with:

```
    function get_users_by_faculty($faculty) { 
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM owner";
    $user_set = mysql_query($query); // ERROR could not establish link to server
    confirm_query($user_set);  
    foreach($user_set as $user) { //ERROR invalid argument
        $userFaculty = get_info_by_id($user["ownerId"], "ou"); 
        if($faculty == $userFaculty){
            return $user["name"];
        } else {
            return NULL; 
        }
    }
```

I've been quite stuck on this for a few hours.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: You should also read up about `WHERE` clauses. Your code is equivalent of going to a grocery store, buying up the entire store's inventory, driving home, then throwing it all out because you only wanted a chocolate bar.

Comment: +1 the question -- N Vidovic is making a fine effort there.  Tereško, THANKS for your answer -- I think you should post it as an full answer.

Comment: @MarcB Well, not quite. It would be like going to the grocery store, buying all the chocolate bars, and throwing out only the ones that aren't made by Hershey. It's not a big database. And I don't know a WHERE statement that allows me to retrieve just one column.

Comment: How are you connecting to the database, it seems that is your first and biggest problem?

Comment: @jeroen I have a connection.php file and call include_once("connection.php") at the top of my code. It's been sufficient in the past

Comment: @N Vidovic Well, if mysql cannot establish a link to the server, it seems it's not :-)

Comment: @n vidovic: `select somefield FROM yourtable WHERE fieldname=fieldvalue`. It's not rocket science. Using `select *` is 'lazy'.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for clarifying, I often mistake searching databases with rocket science. If you read my question, you would realise that your solution does not work. I only have access to the usernames in the database. They make up an entire column. I want to make a list consisting of the usernames (ie the column itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your fields names, but I think you could do that with an sql query.

something like that :

```
SELECT user.id,user.name, faculty.name 
FROM user inner join faculty on faculty.id = user.faculty_id
WHERE faculty.id=?
```

You should replace ? with your faculty id.

If you want a list of user names, you can use group concat :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user.name SEPARATOR ';') 
FROM user inner join faculty on faculty.id = user.faculty_id
WHERE faculty.id=?
GROUP BY faculty.id
```

Comment: Hey, that is a good suggestion but my problem is actually a bit more complicated. I only have the usernames in the database. I then want to insert each of these usernames in another function. The said function has access to a command-line program that stores the information (like the faculty name, for example) on that user